# remove and replace spaces in columns for multiple dataframes

Tags: python-3.x

I was just wondering if there's a way of replacing blanks with underscore in column names, for multiple data frames, l tried this but didn't work:

```
df_columns = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
for i in df_columns:
    df_columns.replace(' ', '_')
```

I've also tried

```
df_columns = {df_1:['iQ Name', 'Cx Name'], df_2:'Cn class'}
for key in df_columns:
    key.columns.replace(' ', '_')
```

and then I get this error:

`TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['iQ Name','Cx Name'] )
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Cn Class'])

df_columns = df_1.columns.tolist() + df_2.columns.tolist()
df_columns = [item.replace(' ', '_') for item in df_columns]

df_columns
```

give you the output you are looking for? It would concatenate the column names into one list, remove the spaces and return them as a list.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it bensonium. I tried it but, I then got this error:  ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (4,)```    :(

Comment: Apologies -answer is revised to include the conversion of the labels tolist which is necessary before concatenating to one list.